# Create SearchView in android with custom layout

Tags: android, android-custom-view, searchview

I want to create a view like this : 
[image: SearchView Mock]

It was simple to do the SearchView but how to create a extending layout below action bar or however to provide some search selection to user while searching.

I want to show a layout which will pop up when user clicks the search icon on action bar. The layout will have the additional search criteria to be selected by user.

Any Hints and Example will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest maybe implementing the menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener() -- when it is expanded, you can show/animate your other view below the action bar.  See docs for OnActionExpandListener.